# How to check if all input (text, email, number and radio) of a div are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Looking for a way to enable the submit button of a form when all its inputs are checked/not empty.

I have stumbled upon snippets in both google and other SO questions, where a similar thing is done, but always only for the same type of input, not considering different kinds as it's the case here. Any ideas how to do this?

Below, an example of where I would use such snippet and its link to http://jsfiddle.net/bRKuV/.

P.S Looking for a solution other than the `required` HTML5 attribute.

EDIT: grouped radios with name attr.

```
<div id="first">
    <form>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text">

        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email">

        <label>Age</label>
        <input type="number" maxlength="2">

        <label>Gender</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m">Male</input>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="f">Female</input>

        <input type="submit" disabled>

    </form>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <form>
        <label>Question 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="y">Yes</input>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="n">No</input>

        <label>Question 2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="y">Yes</input>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="n">No</input>

        <input type="submit" disabled>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt on your own?  If so, it would be helpful to include that here.

Comment: You need to *group* the radio buttons using the `name` attribute.

Comment: Update your jsfiddle too, btw add it your javascript/jquery attempt if any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, *nothing* simpler than this:

```
$("form").on("change", function() {
    $("input").each(function() {
        var test = {radio:1, checkbox:1}[this.type] ? $(this).is(":checked") : !!this.value;
        if(this.type !== "submit") console.log(test);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bRKuV/3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The fiddle you provided isn't working though.

Comment: @nunos Sure?! Change some inputs and take a look at your console. ;)

Comment: Didn't even notice the console.log calls. Thanks for your reply. It was the starting point for my to get to the desired solution I leave here, if any stumbles upon here later. Thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/bRKuV/9/